# Redux not working on expo app for iOs device testing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

everyone, I am creating a food ordering app using react-native on the expo. I have a tab system where my home tab shows menu items. Whenever the user clicks on the "Add To card button" on one of the items in the home tab, the items data gets stored in redux. Then when the user goes to the Cart tab, the cart page loads the items put in redux. Now, when I test this application using the Expo client app. It works fine on the android device. I see the home tab and if I click on any item to be put on the cart, I can see changes on the cart items. But when I run the same application on the iOs device, it does not show any changes on the cart items page. It is always blank.

Here are versions of my node modules

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code? An Expo snack? Online sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this issue but it was out of the blue. When I cloned my project on another laptop and ran npm install the app starting to work on iOS as well. I think the redux version got updated and fixed the error.